# d3.js layout for dependencies graph?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to visualize an unidirectional dependencies graph.
I've done a version using http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292 but I find it impractical, especially with large graphs.
I'm looking for clearly layered nodes, based on their dependency depth. Kind of something like visualizing db referential integrity data (entities with foreign keys).
Any ideas or pointers about existing such layouts?

Comment: You should read this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions. This question is too wide.

Comment: Something like [**this**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550)?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a unidirectional dependency graph -- no loops -- you should look at the [tree or cluster layouts](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Layouts).  The difference is that the tree layout positions nodes from the root down and the cluster layout positions them from the leaf up (so all leaves are at the same level).  Both are static layouts, no bouncing around and overlap like the force layout.

Check out the examples on the wiki:  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery